# MySQL UNION ALL create column from Alias

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

I have a query with a union all that gets data from 3 different tables. The query works just fine, but what I would like to accomplish is to get KWH and Present Demand as actual columns with their corresponding values, instead of being an alias filter column that identify the kind of value is referencing.

```
I would like to have the following
name     kwh        Demand   date
meter1   10252.25   25.35    2014-11-06
```

Here I attach the MySQL query.

```
SELECT
ds.name as KWH_Name,
ROUND(pv.pointValue,2) as KWH,
FROM_UNIXTIME(pv.ts/1000) as Date,
'KWH' as Filter

FROM 
mango.pointvalues as pv,
mango.datapoints as dp,
mango.datasources as ds

where
pv.dataPointId = dp.id and
FROM_UNIXTIME(pv.ts/1000) > '2014-10-31' and
dp.dataSourceId = ds.id and
ds.xid in ('DS_151181','DS_495799','DS_432821','DS_067251','DS_896060','DS_056870','DS_975807','DS_144197','DS_851933','DS_092150','DS_581587','DS_683881','DS_654410','DS_778982','DS_484407','DS_618254') and
dp.xid in ('DP_527107','DP_679864','DP_094433','DP_258167','DP_302281','DP_424331','DP_695840','DP_150558','DP_160298','DP_971876','DP_968565','DP_263818','DP_244594','DP_923944','DP_561553','DP_865672')

UNION ALL

SELECT
ds.name as KWH_Name,
ROUND(pv.pointValue,2) as PRESENT_DEMAND,
FROM_UNIXTIME(pv.ts/1000) as Date,
'PRESENT DEMAND' as Filter

FROM 
mango.pointvalues as pv,
mango.datapoints as dp,
mango.datasources as ds

where
pv.dataPointId = dp.id and
FROM_UNIXTIME(pv.ts/1000) > '2014-10-31' and
dp.dataSourceId = ds.id and
ds.xid in ('DS_151181','DS_495799','DS_432821','DS_067251','DS_896060','DS_056870','DS_975807','DS_144197','DS_851933','DS_092150','DS_581587','DS_683881','DS_654410','DS_778982','DS_484407','DS_618254') and
dp.xid in ('DP_156052','DP_330754','DP_785426','DP_803690','DP_948480','DP_463738','DP_970137','DP_464935','DP_522683','DP_143012','DP_840629','DP_166536','DP_271470','DP_272164','DP_828573','DP_221039')
```

Comment: Other than the `Filter` column, what is the difference between the two subqueries?  Also, you should learn proper explicit `join` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are essentially the same except for the `dp.xid` list.  You can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ds.name as KWH_Name,
       FROM_UNIXTIME(pv.ts/1000) as Date,
       SUM(case when dp.xid in ('DP_527107','DP_679864','DP_094433','DP_258167','DP_302281','DP_424331','DP_695840','DP_150558','DP_160298','DP_971876','DP_968565','DP_263818','DP_244594','DP_923944','DP_561553','DP_865672')
                then pv.pointValue
           end) as KWH,
       SUM(case when dp.xid in ('DP_156052','DP_330754','DP_785426','DP_803690','DP_948480','DP_463738','DP_970137','DP_464935','DP_522683','DP_143012','DP_840629','DP_166536','DP_271470','DP_272164','DP_828573','DP_221039')
                then pv.pointValue
           end) as PresentDemand
FROM mango.pointvalues pv JOIN
     mango.datapoints dp
     ON pv.dataPointId = dp.id JOIN
     mango.datasources ds
     ON dp.dataSourceId = ds.id 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(pv.ts/1000) > '2014-10-31' and
      ds.xid in ('DS_151181','DS_495799','DS_432821','DS_067251','DS_896060','DS_056870','DS_975807','DS_144197','DS_851933','DS_092150','DS_581587','DS_683881','DS_654410','DS_778982','DS_484407','DS_618254')
GROUP BY ds.name, FROM_UNIXTIME(pv.ts/1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It does not work because is returning only 1 record with the addition of all the values for kwh and present demand. I need all of them, with their individual values.

Comment: @AlejandroMiranda . . . The `group by` should make all the difference.

Comment: You are a genius, thank you very much for your quick response. You saved me a huge headache.